# Java Compile Error: Cannot Find Symbol (EraserThread)

Tags: java, compilation, symbols

New to Java, working from a template.   Any idea what's wrong? I'm using Netbeans IDE and uploading the java file to a linux machine and I'm compiling there.

```
PasswordField.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class EraserThread
location: class PasswordField
  EraserThread et = new EraserThread(prompt);
  ^
PasswordField.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class EraserThread
location: class PasswordField
  EraserThread et = new EraserThread(prompt);
                        ^
2 errors
```

---

```
public class PasswordField { 
public static String readPassword (String prompt) {
  EraserThread et = new EraserThread(prompt);
  Thread mask = new Thread(et);
  mask.start();

  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String password = "";

  try {
     password = in.readLine();
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
  // stop masking
  et.stopMasking();
  // return the password entered by the user
  return password;
} 
}
```

Comment: Well where is the `EraserThread` class declared?

Comment: import EraserThread class..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm VERY new to this, but this was a template found online and I get that the error is saying it can't find the class...am I just supposed to create an empty EraserThread class? the template was given just like that.

Comment: If you can depend on Java 6 or newer, please do not use this EraserThread kludge, which will eat all your CPU if you accidentally leave the program running (and not type anything) while entering the password. Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword() instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create (or copy) the EraserThread class. Here is the code. You'll want to go to your project explorer and in the same package that you created the above class, create a new class called "EraserThread". Then paste this into the class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.*;

public class EraserThread implements Runnable {
    private boolean stop;

    /**
    *@param The prompt displayed to the user
    */
    public EraserThread(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
    }

    /**
    * Begin masking...display asterisks (*)
    */
    public void run () {
        stop = true;
        while (stop) {
            System.out.print("/010*");
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1);
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Instruct the thread to stop masking
    */
    public void stopMasking() {
        this.stop = false;
    }
}
```

Once you have the class created, you should be able to run your code.

Code source: http://code.google.com/p/testsome/source/browse/trunk/test/src/EraserThread.java?r=3

**EDIT:** 
I'm not sure if this class already exists elsewhere. You might be able to import it without creating it, but I don't know for sure. Just create this class yourself and you should be ok, and not have to import it through code.

Comment: No the class doesn't exist, thank you so much! New to java, only work with PHP..thanks!!!!

Comment: Hi, I just got around to adding the class. And while I don't receive errors, I do receive this...

Comment: 010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/0010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*/010*

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the System.out.println("/010*") is there for, I was hoping someone else might be able to pick up on this. I haven't used the class myself, just run across it once or twice.